# Modifying Headers Depending on Annotation

Tags: cxf

I wanted to modify the outgoing headers on a client interface depending on the annotation on the request method. For example:

```
@Path("/myservices")
public interface MyService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/something")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @MyAnnotation("value")
    String getsomething(
        @QueryParam("first_param") String firstParam,
        @QueryParam("second_param") int secondParam);
```

The `getsomething` method has a annotation `MyAnnotation`, which an interceptor [out interceptor perhaps] can check if it exists and modify the headers accordingly. I am able to modify the headers in the out interceptor but how do I check for the annotation? The underlying class is no more and I suppose I am way beyond interface and dealing with raw request/response.

Is there any other way of doing this? I could place the annotation at the class level and before `JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create`. I could check the class annotation and stuff the headers into the client. However, I would prefer it at method level. Any suggestions? Note this is for client interface.